# How to call a unique registered gen_server process?

Tags: erlang, gen-server

I'm new to Erlang and I'm trying to build a simple game server (learning purpose).

I have one client controller (supervisor) that creates multiple client handlers (gen_server). I have also one game controller (supervisor) that creates multiple game handlers (gen_server).

One game handler (game table) will then communicate with several client handlers (players). I create the client handlers like this:

client_handler.erl:

```
    start_link(ClientId, UniqueId) ->
    ClientHandlerId = utils:create_id(?MODULE, UniqueId), //client_handler_0 

    State = #state{client_id = ClientId, client_handler_id = ClientHandlerId},

    gen_server:start_link({global, ClientHandlerId}, ?MODULE, State, []).
```

game_handler.erl:

```
    start_link(ClientHandlerId, GameId, UniqueId) ->    

    GameHandlerId = utils:create_id(?MODULE, UniqueId), //game_handler_0

    State = #state{client_handler_id = ClientHandlerId, game_id = GameId, game_handler_id = GameHandlerId},

    gen_server:start_link({global, GameHandlerId}, ?MODULE, State, []).
```

My problem is that I want to talk between client_handler and game_handler without neither of them knowing about their inner structure. For now I use:

client_handler.erl:

```
    gen_server:cast(game_handler_0, {make_move, MoveData}).
```

and this works great. However, I would like to use:

client_handler.erl:

```
    game_handler_0:make_move(MoveData)
```

So I can build separate API:s for each module (only use -export functions). Is this possible?

Best regards,
xqtr

EDIT: typo

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is considered good practice to abstract away implementation details in that way. Just move the `cast` call into a function in `game_handler.erl`, something like:

```
make_move(UniqueId, MoveData) ->
    GameHandlerId = utils:create_id(?MODULE, UniqueId),
    gen_server:cast(GameHandlerId, {make_move, MoveData}).
```

and export `make_move/2`.  (Or perhaps forget about `UniqueId`, and pass `GameHandlerId` directly to the `make_move` function.)

Comment: Hi @legoscia and thanks for the reply! There will be both unique client handlers and unique game handlers. The Client controller will create a unique client handler, say 'client_handler_5'. This registered atom will then be passed to the Game controller which in turn will create a unique game handler, say 'game_handler_22'. Would I be able to connect with the client handler by just making a function in client_handler like connect(GameHandlerId) and then call it in game handler with:
client_handler_5:connect(game_handler_22)?

Do I have to globally register the names in gen_server:start_link?